# Excel If Function Error

Tags: excel, if-statement, text

I'm trying to create a function that test different values in 3 columns in order for correctness. 
Explanation of the intended code:
If the first character of column A is an x, the number in column C is 20, and column G value is equal to column U then it is correct and prints yes. If the first character in column a isn't an x and column C is equal to 20 and column H is equal to column U then it is correct and prints yes. For all else if the values in column G are equal to those in column U then the function prints yes otherwise it prints no.

The specific error is invalid name error.

This is what I see when I go to see calculation:

```
IF(FALSE,#N/A,IF(TRUE,#NAME?,IF(G3=U3,yes,no)))
```

Here is the function ,but I can not find how to fix the error.

```
=IF(AND(RIGHT(A3,1)="x",C3="20", G3=U3),"yes",IF(AND(NOT(RIGHT(A3,1)="x"),C3="20",H3=U3),yes,IF(G3=U3,yes,no)))
```

I went to see calculation, and the error is located where the first yes is, but I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: You may also want to remove the "" from around `C3="20"`.  It's treating the 20 as text rather than a number.  Try this example:  Type `20` into cell `A1`.  The formula `=A1="20"` returns _False_ as _"20"_ is text and _20_ is a number.  `=A1=20` returns _True_.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the way yes is typed into the formula. It requires "" because it is text.

I figured it out after I evaluated the function with the calculation steps button. Then I saw where the error was occurring based on the evaluation and manipulated the function.